# Do I need to embed a LinearLayout into another for inclusion into a ListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In order to create an XML resource file to be included via tools:listitem="@layout/row", I was told to create an XML structure like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/reminder_row">

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now... is it important to have the second LinearLayout nested into the first one? Are there good reasons why I can't do this instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering you are told by whom to do the first xml? The second one should totally work. Just don't forget to include the orientation.

And tools:xxx is just for IDE preview purposes, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ta! "I'm wondering you are told by whom to do the first xml?" The book "Learn Android Studio --  Build Android Apps Quickly and Effectively"